# IMO long list spatial Combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, problem-solving, matching-theory

Can anyone send a solution or hint to these problem? I tried a greedy algorithm but couldn’t make it work[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the finitely many possible pairings, choose one for which the sum of the lengths of the line segments is least.

**Claim:**$\;$For such a pairing, no two line segments intersect.

Suppose for such a pairing the line segments $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $P$.

Then $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral with diagonals intersecting at $P$.

But then if we replace the pairs $A,C$ and $B,D$ by $A,B$ and $C,D$ we would have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
|AB| &< |AP|+|PB|\\[4pt]
|CD| &< |CP|+|PD|\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
\right.
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
|AB| + |CD| &< (|AP|+|PB|)+(|CP|+|PD|)\\[4pt]
&= (|AP|+|CP|)+(|PB|+|PD|)\\[4pt]
&= (|AP|+|PC|)+(|BP|+|PD|)\\[4pt]
&= |AC|+|BD|\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so the new pairing would have a smaller sum of segment lengths, contradiction.

Comment: How would someone think about this fairly specific condition?

Comment: From a diagram of an intersecting pair of line segments, the triangle inequalities make it clear that the sum of the segment lengths can be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Form the convex hull of the $2n$ points, and let $x$ and $y$ be adjacent extreme points. Then you can join $x$ with $y$, and pair up the remaining $2n-2$ points by induction.